# How to use Fetch api with arrayBuffer response type and React Native?

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm currently using Fetch API with my RN project. It works well with `text` and `json` response types, but it doesn't work with [arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer)

```
let res = await fetch('http://example.com');
let data = await res.arrayBuffer();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

It seems it hasn't been added in to the React Native implementation yet. In the mean time `XMLHTTPRequest` seems to have all the functionality of the browser version.

```
function get(url) {
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        req.onload = function(event) {
            var resp = req.response;
            if(resp) {
                accept(resp);
            }
        };

        req.send(null);
    });
}

...

let data = await get('http://example.com');
```

Note: This doesn't `reject` on errors and is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: This worked in mid 2022. Thanks!